# Output: Skipping target because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files while running msbuild from console app

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

**While running my msbuild instead of building the project , it skips the file and gives an out put as :
**Output: Skipping target because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files while running msbuild from console app**
**Output:   Running generator on: D:\git\abc\gen.xsl\MediaInputIdMap.cs.xsl**
What i have noticed is while execution it invokes default cmd.exe instead of 2017 cmd.exe even when i have changed the default to %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" in Tools > Options > Terminal , how do i invoke a 2017 command prompt while executing my console app?, it is still picking up cmd.exe**

```
 class Program
    {
        
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
            log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        bool retvalue = false;
            string LogPath = @"D:\Logs\";
            string solutionpath = @"D:\git\abc\Build\Tools";
            string msBuildPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)), @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin");
            string solutionFilename = solutionpath;
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(solutionFilename);

            Console.WriteLine("Printing current working directory :{0} \n\n\n ", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
            string RMPath = @"D:\git\abc\RMS";
            string RMSolution = ResourceManagerPath;

            try
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(LogPath)) 
                {
                    log.Info("Log Directory Exists, Starting execution");
                    Console.WriteLine(LogPath, "Directory Exists {0}");
                    log.Debug("Checking for Log Directory, It Exists !!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(LogPath, "Doesn't Exists, Creating the Folder");
                    DirectoryInfo LogPathfolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(LogPath);
                    log.Info("Creating LogPath Folder");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                log.Error(e.Message);
            }
           
            try
            {
               
                    log.Info("SETUP");
                    Console.WriteLine("Running Setup Commands: \n\n\n");
                    retvalue = RunMSBuild(msBuildPath, "/t:setup");
                    log.Debug(retvalue);

                    if (retvalue)
                    {
                        log.Info("Build");
                        Console.WriteLine("Running Build Commands: \n\n\n");
                        retvalue = RunMSBuild(msBuildPath, "/t:debug;pbuild");
                        log.Debug(retvalue);


                        if (retvalue)
                        {
                            log.Info("Build");
                            Console.WriteLine("Running Build Commands: \n\n\n");
                            retvalue = RunMSBuild(msBuildPath, "/t:debug;mpbuild /m");
                            log.Debug(retvalue);

                            if (retvalue)
                            {
                                log.Info("Build");
                                Console.WriteLine("Running Build Commands: \n\n\n");
                                retvalue = RunMSBuild(msBuildPath, "/t:debug;pbuild /m");
                                log.Debug(retvalue);

                                if (retvalue)
                                {
                                    log.Info("Nuget Package Restore");
                                    Console.WriteLine("Restoring Nuget Packages for abc.sln \n\n\n\n");
                                    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(RMSolution);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Running Dotnet Restore");
                                    var stdOutDR = new StringBuilder();
                                    var stdErrDR = new StringBuilder();

                                    var DotRest = await Cli.Wrap("dotnet")
                                        .WithArguments("restore")
                                        .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(stdOutDR))
                                        .WithStandardErrorPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(stdErrDR))
                                        .ExecuteBufferedAsync();

                                    var stdOut1 = stdOutDR.ToString();
                                    var stdErr1 = stdErrDR.ToString();

                                    
                                    Console.WriteLine("Dotnet Restore Nuget Package Completed : \n {0}", stdOut1);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Dotnet Restore Nuget Package Error : \n {0}", stdErr1);

                                    var stdOutNR = new StringBuilder();
                                    var stdErrNR = new StringBuilder();

                                    var NugRest = await Cli.Wrap("nuget")
                                        .WithArguments("restore")
                                        .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(stdOutNR))
                                        .WithStandardErrorPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(stdErrNR))
                                        .ExecuteBufferedAsync();

                                    var stdOut2 = stdOutNR.ToString();
                                    var stdErr2 = stdErrNR.ToString();

                                    Console.WriteLine("Nuget Restore Packages");
                                    Console.WriteLine("Nuget Restore completed : \n {0}",stdOut2);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Nuget Restore Error : \n {0}",stdErr2);

                                    log.Info("ResourceManagerMS");
                                        Console.WriteLine("Building ResourceManager.sln");
                                        retvalue = RunMSBuild(msBuildPath, "abc.sln");
                                        log.Debug(retvalue);
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                log.Error(ex.Message);
            }

            




            Console.WriteLine("Build completed");
            Console.ReadKey();
           
        }



        private static bool RunMSBuild(string msBuildPath, string arguments = null)
        {
            try
            {
                //get tools path for newest Visual Studio version
                string msBuildFilename = Path.Combine(msBuildPath, "MSBuild.exe");

                if (!File.Exists(msBuildFilename))
                    throw new Exception($"Error: MSBuild.exe not found ({msBuildFilename})");

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(msBuildFilename)
                {
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
                };



                using (Process p = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
                {
                    //subscribe to event and add event handler code
                    p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                        {
                            //ToDo: add desired code 
                            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
                        }
                    };

                    //subscribe to event and add event handler code
                    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                        {
                            //ToDo: add desired code
                            Console.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
                        }
                    };

                    //start
                    p.Start();

                    p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
                    p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

                    //waits until the process is finished before continuing
                    p.WaitForExit();

                    p.CancelErrorRead(); //cancel async reading for standard error
                    p.CancelOutputRead(); //cancel async reading for standard output
                    return true;
                }
            }
           catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error {0}",ex.Message);
                return false;

            }

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: How do i execute the steps which internally calls my project without skipping it

Comment: What is the content of the *.*proj file in the 'D:\git\abc\Build\Tools' directory?

Comment: What i have noticed is while execution it invokes default cmd.exe instead of 2017 cmd.exe even when i have changed the default to %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" in Tools > Options > Terminal , how do i invoke a 2017 command prompt while executing my console app?, it is still picking up cmd.exe , can i change the terminal to invoke 2017 while executing console app?